# How to save stream with ffmpeg to chunks, But in temporary name and change the name after to const

Tags: ffmpeg

I use  ffmpeg to record IP camera and I save every 10 minutes to mp4 file.
This is my code:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i "rtsp://$user_name:$password@$IP:$port/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1" -c copy -map 0 -reset_timestamps 1  -f segment -segment_time 600 -strftime 1   "%Y-%m-%d__%H:%M:%S.mp4"
```

Is there a way to save the file in temporary name until 10 minutes is done?
I mean when the recording of  10 minutes didn't end the suffix will be bla.temp and when the recording of the  10 minutes is over, ffmpeg will change the suffix to .mp4?
is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

That is not a feature of ffmpeg. You will need to write that code yourself.

Comment: I know how to write it in bash, for example when I download file with wget i can save it with a temporary name and when the download has done I change the name. But because the FFmpeg creates the files in himself how can I combine it with FFmpeg code?

Answer (score 0):

For rtp streams this command works, probably it could also work for rtsp:

`ffmpeg -i rtp://0.0.0.0:5010 -c pcm_mulaw -f segment -segment_time 10 -strftime 1 '%Y%m%d_%H%M%S.wav'`

segment_time in seconds

-strftime 1 needed for the naming of the output file if using timestamp